# Cannot implicitly convert Web.Http.Results.JsonResult to Web.Mvc.JsonResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5, jsonresult

I've set up this test method on a controller to strip out any complication to it.  Based off of all the results I've found from searching this should work.  I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

```
public JsonResult test() 
{
    return Json(new { id = 1 });
}
```

This is the error I get.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'

Comment: Note how the *immediate problem* has nothing to do with anonymous types.

Comment: `Json(object data)` method that returns desired `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult` is _protected_ method of `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`. You need to inherit from Controller class to be able to use that. If your controller inherits from (eg) ApiController (as in my case;-) you are using `Json<T>(T content)` method that returns `System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<T>`...

Answer (score 12):

you should return a JsonResult instead of just Json

```
 public JsonResult test() 
    {
        var result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = new
        {
             id = 1
         };
        result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
public System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult test() 
{
    return Json(new { id = 1 });
}
```

It seems that `Json` does not generate a `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult` which is expected as you are probably `using System.Web.Mvc;` but a `System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult`.
The more generic one should also work:

```
public ActionResult test() 
{
    return Json(new { id = 1 });
}
```

**NOTE:**
In my MVC controllers the `Json` method does return a `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult`. Are you inheriting from the default `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`?

Comment: @ToanNguyen: Yes and no. For me the initial code is working, as `Json` does return a `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult` in my controllers. But according to the exception it does not in his case...

Answer (score 1):

Try

`return Json(new { id = 1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the data through a model class rather than an anonymous class. Like:

```
public System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<modelClass> test(){
        return Json(new modelClass(){ id=1 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MVC `JsonResult` is inherited from `ActionResult`  which is in namespace `System.Web.Mvc`

thats why you should make the Reference to `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult` as::

```
public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult test() 
{
    return Json(new { id = 1 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Using:

```
using System.Web.Http.Results;
```

Then Your Action:

```
public JsonResult<YourClass> Get(string Search)
        {
           var Search = Search
           return Json(Search);
        }
```