# Getting HttpReques does not contain definition for Form - Datatable server side processing

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have the following server side code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using AutoMapper;
using myProject.Models;
using System.Web.Http;
using MyProject.Dtos;

using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Data.Entity;
public class MembersController: Controller 
{
     public MembersController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        }

public ActionResult GetMembers(string query = null)
        {
            try
            {
                //Creating instance of DatabaseContext class  
                using (_context)
                {
                    var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
                    var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
                    var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();



                    //Paging Size (10,20,50,100)    
                    int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
                    int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
                    int recordsTotal = 0;

                    // Getting all member data    
                    var membersQuery = _context.Members.ToList();



                    //total number of rows count     
                    recordsTotal = membersQuery.Count();
                    //Paging     
                    var data = membersQuery.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                    ////Returning Json Data    
                    return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data });


                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }

}
```

Here's my view:

```
var table = $("#members").DataTable({
        "processing": true, // for show progress bar  
        "serverSide": true,
        "pageLength":5,

        ajax: {
            url: "/api/members",
            dataSrc: "",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json" 

        },

        columns: [
            {
                data: "cardNumber"
            },
            {
                data: "registrationDate",

            },
            {
                data: "fullName",

            },
            {
                data: "address"
            },
            {
                data: "phoneNumber"
            },
            {
                data: "email"
            }             
        ]
    });
```

I am getting the following compile errors:

> Error   CS1061  'HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for 'Form' and no accessible extension method 'Form' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequestMessage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult< data>>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'

I am following [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-datatables-grid-with-asp-net-mvc/) tutorial for guidance.

Will appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Both exception messages are related each other, and seem originated from this `using` statement which was suspicious:

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

And this `url` setting which implies that you want to call Web API controller from DataTable's AJAX callback:

```
url: "/api/members", // points to Web API controller
```

The first exception occurred because you're using `Request` property which not originated from [`HttpContext.Request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.request?view=netframework-4.7.2) that returns [`HttpRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest?view=netframework-4.7.2), instead it came from another `Request` property in `System.Web.Http` namespace which returns [`HttpRequestMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh159020(v%3Dvs.118)).

The second exception occurred because return type of the controller action is `System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult`, while your `Json()` method might return `System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult` which is part of Web API.

Judging from your AJAX URL and controller action, you have 2 options:

1) If you're using **MVC controller**, remove `System.Web.Http` namespace and make sure you're using `Request` from `HttpContext.Current` like example below:

```
var draw = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
var start = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
var length = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
```

Then you need to replace AJAX call in `DataTable` to call the action name like this:

```
ajax: {
    url: '@Url.Action("GetMember", "Members")',
    data: ..., // set your data here
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json" 
},
```

2) If you're using **Web API controller**, replace `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` inheritance with `System.Web.Http.ApiController`, then use proper way to return JSON string from Web API controller:

```
public class MembersController: ApiController 
{
    // ctor
    public MembersController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();

    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetMembers([FromBody] ViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            //Creating instance of DatabaseContext class  
            using (_context)
            {
                var draw = model.Draw;
                var start = model.Start;
                var length = model.Length;

                // skipped for brevity

                return Ok(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // error handling
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you choose this approach, you can leave the URL `/api/Members` as is but the AJAX call's `data`/`dataSrc` parameter from `DataTable` should be modified to pass the viewmodel object because `Request` property from Web API doesn't have `Form` property as its member.

Related issues:

[POST throws HttpRequestMessage does not contain a definition for Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277058/post-throws-httprequestmessage-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-form)

[Cannot implicitly convert Web.Http.Results.JsonResult to Web.Mvc.JsonResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075409/cannot-implicitly-convert-web-http-results-jsonresult-to-web-mvc-jsonresult)

Comment: Hi @Tetsuya, thanks for your insights. I opted for option 1 (MVC Controller) and when I started to debug, I got the following exception on the very first line where it  tries to read the value of "draw". This is what I got: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source